# Python on VSCode not Running on the Selected Environment

Tags: python, numpy, visual-studio-code

I have a bit of a weird issue that I couldn't find an answer to on Google. I'm trying to use Python on VSCode (quite new to it, I've been using PyCharm till now), but for some reason when I try to import and use Numpy or PyTorch, it throws a ModuleNotFoundError (see below).

I've double checked to ensure I've selected the right environment *and* that Numpy and PyTorch are both installed in this specific environment.

This code also works without issue in this environment if I try it on PyCharm, so the issue seems to be entirely in VSCode alone. Note, I'm  using the [Code Runner extension by Jun Han](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) to run this.

Please help! Thank you.

[image: Error message.]

Comment: what happens if you don't use Code Runner and use the built-in VSCode runner?

Comment: Looks like it's running `python` (without any specific pathname). If you run that same python from the VS Code terminal and simply import numpy, does it also fail?

Comment: It works perfectly fine if I run it from the terminal, but the issue persists with the built in runner.

Comment: Presumably, numpy was installed into a different installation of Python.

Comment: @jarmod I've triple checked and the library Numpy definitely exists in this environment.

Comment: I would modify your script to print PYTHONPATH and sys.path. See if that explains things.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your suggestions. Reinstalling everything (Conda and VSCode, as well as PyTorch) fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

The file is located on your desktop but the file should be somewhere where it has access to "python\Lib\site-packages" folder where numpy should be installed.

1.go to your folder where python is installed.

2.go to the folder called "scripts" and make a .py file in there, try to run the same code and if the "ModuleNotFoundError" isn't fixed yet.

3.reinstall numpy from the terminal in the file thats located in the scripts folder. I had the same issue but putting my file into the "scripts" folder fixed it for me.

If this dosent work just tell me. :^)

Comment: None of this worked for me. I should mention, this works fine if I try to run it either via the terminal or even via PyCharm!